# How to reply to a post in a channel and append to original message

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, microsoft-teams

Can anyone direct me on how to correctly thread a conversation in Teams?

By threading I mean replying to someone's post in a channel and appending it to their original message.

Comment: You can quote reply 1:1 chat messages in MS Teams but cannot edit the messages by others.

Comment: For posts in MS teams channel, you get "Reply" option under new post/conversation where you can reply to existing messages.